# OpenSSL: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]

Tags: java, https, openssl, tomcat8, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to make the SSL installation of my website and configure its HTTPS settings.
I installed Tomcat 8.0.3 on Ubuntu 22.04. The java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_382-8u382-ga-1~22.04.1-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
```

I got letsencrypt certificate using acme.sh:

`acme.sh --issue --dns dns_namesilo -d example.com -d www.example.com --dnssleep 2000`

```
root@server:/# acme.sh --list                                                                                
Main_Domain  KeyLength  SAN_Domains      CA               Created               Renew        
example.com  "ec-256"   www.example.com  LetsEncrypt.org  2023-11-02T19:40:54Z  2023-12-31T19:40:54Z
```

acme.sh created these certificate files:

```
SSLCertificateFile="/root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer"
SSLCACertificateFile="/root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/ca.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="/root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.key"
```

Then I had to import the certificate and the key as PrivateKeyEntry:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.cer -inkey /root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.key -name example.com -out example.com.p12

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeystore /root/.keystore -srckeystore example.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

Now I have two files: example.com.jks and example.com.p12. But the first one is trustedCertEntry:

```
root@server:/# keytool -list -keystore /example.com.jks
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

example.com, Nov 5, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256)
```

The .p12 one ise the PrivateKeyEntry:

```
root@server:/# keytool -list -keystore /example.com.p12
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

example.com, Nov 5, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256)
```

So I changed the server.xml like this:

```
...
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreAlias="example.com"
               keystoreFile="/example.com.p12"
               keystorePass="changeit"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
...
```

But it didn't work.

The error message I encounter is as follows:

```
root@server:/# openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
4047E1C40B7F0000:error:8000006F:system library:BIO_connect:Connectionrefused:../crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:125:calling connect()
4047E1C40B7F0000:error:10000067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:127:connect:errno=111
```

Then I noticed that port 443 is closed:

```
root@server:/# nmap -p 443 example.com --reason
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-06 23:36 +03
Nmap scan report for example.com
Host is up, received localhost-response (0.00012s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE REASON
443/tcp closed https   reset ttl 64

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.29 seconds
```

```
root@server:/# netstat -anltp | grep LISTEN                                                                  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      229/systemd-resolve          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      336/sshd: /usr/sbin          
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      254540/java                  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      336/sshd: /usr/sbin          
tcp6     101      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      254540/java                  
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      254540/java                  
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      254540/java
```

Appears on the ufw list:

```
root@server:/# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 8443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

The detailed status of other ports is as follows:

```
root@server:/# lsof -i:8080
COMMAND    PID     USER     FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME
java       254540  tomcat   57u  IPv6     2619532819       0t0   TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

```
root@server:/# lsof -i:8443
COMMAND    PID     USER     FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME                                              
java       254540  tomcat   58u  IPv6     2619532820       0t0   TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
```

```
root@server:/# lsof -i:80
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE  NAME                                                   
dhpcd    431  root   10u  IPv4     2625048130        0t0   TCP server.example.com:36174->ns31430745.ip-141-94-96.eu:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've read that acme.sh doesn't use IPv6, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I have to re-setup my website using old versions of Tomcat and Java and this is causing too many problems. Frankly, I have no clear ideas what I should do at this stage. I will be grateful if you could help me.

**EDIT:**

```
root@server:/# openssl s_client -connect example.com:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 321 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was due to iptables redirection. There are two points to consider at this point. First, to delete prerouting records, you need to use a command like this: iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING... Second, the commands needed to permanently save the change. What worked for me were the following:

```
# /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# /sbin/ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Comment: **Your tomcat (like most) is listening on 8443 and 8080, NOT 443 or 80.** This is the default in the 'standard' config file and usually retained because on Unix using ports below 1024 requires 'root' or a special capability and doing those for Java can be a big security risk. If you're okay with using the alternate ports (many people are), just use `openssl s_client -connect example.com:8443` and similarly use `https://example.com:8443/whatever` in a browser, curl, wget, fetch, etc. If you want the standard ports there are many different approaches but all offtopic here. ...

Comment: ... BTW Java 8u382 is not old at all; TC 8.0.3 is, and thus would be all the more unsafe to run privileged (one of the many approaches I referred to). You would probably be better off with one of the approaches that puts a reverse proxy in front of TC, _both_ to do the SSL/TLS termination _and_ to block attacks using nonstandard, malformed or crafted HTTP; httpd ('apache2' in ubuntu repo) is usually easiest, but nginx is possible and few others.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for the information, but this also gave an error. I added the error message above.

Comment: This is all about the listening port. It has nothing to do with certificates whatsoever.

Comment: Okay, that shows `s_client` did _connect_ at TCP level to 8443 but after the 'hello' message tomcat abnormally closed (104 is ECONNRESET) -- or possibly if your network connection goes through any kind of gateway, firewall or monitoring facility, that could have decided to abort the connection. Check the tomcat logs to see what (it thinks) happened.