# Apache 2.4.52 and mod_jk 1.2.48 not forwarding to Tomcat 8.0.3

Tags: load-balancing, tomcat8, apache2.4, mod-jk, acme.sh

I am trying re-setup my website using Tomcat 8.0.3 on Ubuntu 22.04. The openjdk version is 1.8.0_382.
I haven't been able to complete the SSL installation for weeks. I tried keytool first, but had trouble with the port 443:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77435703/openssl-connectionrefusederror-errno-111](https://stackoverflow.com)
Then I realized it would make more sense to use Apache2 and mod_jk. Currently, there does not seem to be any problem with Apache2 installation, but I still cannot perform the redirection.

My configuration is as follows:

```
# /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.load
LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so

# /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf

# /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf
JkWorkersFile /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties

# /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties
workers.tomcat_home=/opt/tomcat
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker

# /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
JkMountCopy On
JkMount /* ajp13_worker

# /etc/apache2/sites-available/example2.com.conf
ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com/public_html
JkMountCopy On
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
SSLCertificateFile /root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/ca.cer

# /opt/tomcat/server.xml
<Connector port="8009" address="::1" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" />
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="ajp13_worker">
```

I had created the certificates using acme.sh.

I checked the ufw firewall status.

The Apache2 configuration seems OK. The VirtualHost one too.

curl -I https://example.com gives HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

There is no error in mod_jk.log.

This is the Apache2 error log:

```
# less /var/log/apache2/error.log
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 333218:tid 139942839801728] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 333218:tid 139942839801728] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_jk/1.2.48 OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 333218:tid 139942839801728] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And finally, Catalina.out sometimes starts without any problems, sometimes it gives the following error. The problem must be caused by Tomcat, but I couldn't find a permanent solution to it.

```
# tail /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 8009"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 8009"]
INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
 Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

What's the problem that I can't see or solve? Any idea will be appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was due to iptables redirection. There are two points to consider at this point. First, to delete prerouting records, you need to use a command like this: iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING... Second, the commands needed to permanently save the change. What worked for me were the following:

```
# /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# /sbin/ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Comment: mod_jk in apache connects via AJP to port 8009 in Tomcat; the reported errors are on port 8080 which is (or should be) HTTP. Something else, or perhaps muliple things else, is/are doing that, not apache nor Tomcat. Either figure out what the other thing(s) is/are and fix it/them, perhaps simply by blocking connections from anything other than localhost (where I ass-u-me apache is), or ignore this.